# Python optimizing loops for checking number of anagrams

Tags: python, optimization

i am trying to solve a question that provides a string as input and gives the number of anagrams possible as output. this can be solved using dictionaries but i could only think in terms of for loops and string indices.

```
count = 0
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        for j in range(0,len(s)):
            for k in range(j+1,len(s)):
                if(k+i>len(s)):
                    continue
                # print(list(s[j:j+i]),list(s[k:k+i]),j,j+i,k,k+i)
                if(sorted(list(s[j:j+i]))==sorted(list(s[k:k+i]))):
                    count +=1         
    return count
```

i have coded this far and tried for optimization with k+i. can someone tell me other techniques to optimize the code without losing the logic. the code keeps getting terminated due to time-out for larger strings.should i replace `sorted` function with something else.

Comment: It's s[j:j+i] i not 1

Answer (score 2):

The number of anagrams if each letter was unique would be `n!` with `n` as the length of the string (e.g. law has `3!=6`). If there a given letter is repeated, say, twice (e.g. `wall`), then you have twice as many answers as you should (since things like `w-(second l)-(first l)-a` are actually indistinguishable from things like `w-(first l)-(second l)-a`). It turns out that if a letter is repeated `k` times (`k` is 2 for the letter `"l"` in `wall`), `n!` overcounts by a factor of `k!`. This is true for each repeated letter.

So to get the number of anagrams, you can do:

```
letter_counts = get_letter_counts(s) #returns something like [1, 1, 2] when given wall, since there is one w, one a, two ls
n_anagrams = factorial(len(s))

#account for overcounts
for letter_count in letter_counts:
    n_anagrams /= factorial(letter_count)

return n_anagrams
```

Implementing `factorial` and `get_letter_counts` left as an excercise for the reader :-) . Note: Be careful to consider that repeated letters can show up more than once, and not always next to each other. Ex: "aardvark" should return a count of 3 for the "a"s, 2 for the "r"s, and 1 for everything else.

Comment: sounds like a job for `from collections import Counter`  - +1 for the cool math :)

Comment: I was asked for no of anagram pairs... would it make any difference?